# Firebase duplicate cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is possible to avoid duplicating of cell with content of the same name during import customer from database to tableview? In my example if customer Ben Smith has two children with values I want only one cell with his name.

This is my database structure...

[image]

And result in tableview:

[image]

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let usersDatabaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("usersDatabase").child(userID).child("Customers")
    usersDatabaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        print("there are \(snapshot.childrenCount) users")
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            print("user: \(childSnap.key)")
            let userCustomerSnap = childSnap
            for customer in userCustomerSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let customerSnap = customer
                let dict = customerSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                let name = dict["Name and surname"]
                let phone = dict["Phone"]
                let company = dict["Company name"]
                let customerID = dict["ID"]
                let email = dict["Email"]
                let nip = dict["Nip1"]
                let postal = dict["Postal code"]
                let street = dict["Street"]
                let town = dict["Town"]
                let myCustomer = CustomerModel(name: name as? String, phone: phone as? String, company: company as? String, customerID: customerID as? String, email: email as? String, nip: nip as? String, postal: postal as? String, street: street as? String, town: town as? String)
                self.candies.append(myCustomer)
                self.filteredCandies.append(myCustomer)
            }
            self.tableViewCustomer.reloadData()
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @Khushbu update send

Comment: On your lust loop try this:
for customer in userCustomerSnap.children.first

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. what is inside children.first(where: ??? )

Comment: Please share your table view code.

Comment: I answered  check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding an item to the list each time you find an order (or whatever the level under "Ben Smith" represents in your data) from that customer. So your list is a list of orders, not a list of customers.

In general in NoSQL/Firebase, it is recommended to model your database for what you want to display. So if you want a list of customers, that's what I'd store in the database. But given your data structure, you can also fix it in code:

```
usersDatabaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    print("there are \(snapshot.childrenCount) users")
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let myCustomer = CustomerModel(name: child.key, phone: "", company: "", customerID: "", email: "", nip: "", postal: "", street: "", town: ")
        self.candies.append(myCustomer)
        self.filteredCandies.append(myCustomer)
    }

    self.tableViewCustomer.reloadData()
})
```

Or alternatively, only add the new customer when their name is different from the previous order you saw:

```
var previousName: String = ""
usersDatabaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    print("there are \(snapshot.childrenCount) users")
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        print("user: \(childSnap.key)")
        let userCustomerSnap = childSnap
        for customer in userCustomerSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let customerSnap = customer
            let dict = customerSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let name = dict["Name and surname"]
            if name != previousName {
                let phone = dict["Phone"]
                let company = dict["Company name"]
                let customerID = dict["ID"]
                let email = dict["Email"]
                let nip = dict["Nip1"]
                let postal = dict["Postal code"]
                let street = dict["Street"]
                let town = dict["Town"]
                let myCustomer = CustomerModel(name: name as? String, phone: phone as? String, company: company as? String, customerID: customerID as? String, email: email as? String, nip: nip as? String, postal: postal as? String, street: street as? String, town: town as? String)
                self.candies.append(myCustomer)
                self.filteredCandies.append(myCustomer)
                previousName = name
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableViewCustomer.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thanks! You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need that for loop. That might be what's causing you issue. The code is called for the same number of times that you have children anyway so you don't need that loop. Try the code below. If that doesn't work, you might need to try `.childAdded` instead of `.value`

```
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
let usersDatabaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("usersDatabase").child(userID).child("Customers")
usersDatabaseRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

    guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

    let name = dict["Name and surname"] as? String
    let phone = dict["Phone"] as? String
    let company = dict["Company name"] as? String
    let customerID = dict["ID"] as? String
    let email = dict["Email"] as? String
    let nip = dict["Nip1"] as? String
    let postal = dict["Postal code"] as? String
    let street = dict["Street"] as? String
    let town = dict["Town"] as? String

    let myCustomer = CustomerModel(name: name, phone: phone, company: company, customerID: customerID, email: email, nip: nip, postal: postal, street: street, town: town)

    self.candies.append(myCustomer)

    self.filteredCandies.append(myCustomer)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableViewCustomer.reloadData()
    }

}, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: This code show in my tableview only one empty cell - it's not working...

Comment: @KrzysztofŁowiec use .childAdded instead of using .value

Comment: Now i have four empty cell - it's correct number but still empty